# Создание файла на диске C и запись в него

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Если я напишу

```
   ofstream log(TEXT("С:\\TEST\\log.txt"),ios::app);
```

То у меня это будет работать только если вместо системного диска(C) будет стоять любой другой. Создать директорию через

```
CreateDirectory(TEXT("C:\\TEST"), NULL);
```

получается легко. А вот сам файл создать где-либо на диске C никак не выходит. Мне желательно как-нибудь именно через ofstream реализовать это.

Comment: Запуск отдельно исходника от имени администратора ничего не дал.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я разобрался с этим вопросом. Как я понял создавать файлы можно легко в папке и подпапках после AppData, но на каждом компе разные же имена пользователей. Однако и это очень легко решается.Функция getenv("APPDATA") получает местоположение до папки Roaming, а дальше вам остается к ней прикрепить полный путь и вуаля, готово))

```
strcpy(dir, getenv("APPDATA"));
strcat(dir, "\\Microsoft\\");
strcat(logName, dir); //dir- это если вам еще для чего-то надо будет директория.
strcat(logName, "\\log.txt");
ofstream log(logName, ios::app); // и вы создали файл txt на диске С))
```